# Entity Data Model Wizard Not Showing New Tables

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, visual-studio-2012

I've created a sql database from scripts using Microsoft SQL Server 2012 and generated some classes in C# using the entity framework.  Now I've had to modify and add a number of new items to that database, including stored procedures and new tables.

However, on trying to regenerate the classes in Visual Studio Ultimate 2012, the Entity Data Model Wizard is still showing the old database (the way it looked a week ago), including some tables I deleted.  None of the new stuff is listed.  I've tried deleting and recreating the database, restarting both programs, and restarting the pc to no effect.

The steps I'm taking to generate the framework in Visual Studio are:

- Add a new item to the project.
- Select ADO.NET Entity Data Model.
- Select Code First from database.
- Select Next (the connection string is already filled in).
- The next screen is the "Choose Objects and Settings" window, which is where I'm still seeing the old tables (and not the new ones).

Is there some special step I need to take after changing a database to get those changes to show up in the entity framework?

**UPDATE:**

I've got a lead on an option to "Update Model from Database", but my Visual Studio has no option like this.  Web searches indicate it's found in the "Model Browser Window", which I've also not found in VS.  Further searches indicate this window becomes available after opening an "edmx" file.  I've searched the entire pc for that file extension and found some results, but they are all from other peoples' projects.  I can't locate a .edmx associated with either the c# solution or the sql database for this project.

Comment: I don't know a lot about Code First but it appears you are trying to do a database-first strategy.  Selecting Code First might be your problem.  In "choose objects and settings" no doubt you are looking at your model in code not your database.

Comment: @pseudocoder: Is there another option that you would recommend instead?

Comment: When I add an EDM I get the options "Empty Model" or "Generate from database".  There is no mention of "code first" at that point.  I would choose "Generate from database", then ensure my connection string is pointing to the right server/db.  I use EF 6.

Comment: Under "choose options" I don't have an option for "generate from database", but I do have "empty model".  "Code First from Database" is the one I was instructed to use for the project, however.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the Entity Data Model Wizard, on the "Choose Your Data Connection" screen, I chose "New Connection" rather than hitting "Next" with the existing connection.  Choosing the server name and database name and redoing the connection seems to refresh the view, and now the new tables have shown up.

I had a feeling it was going to be some small, ten-second thing I was missing.

**UPDATE:**

Redoing the connection made the new tables available, but not the stored procedures.  Here's how I fixed it.

In the Model Wizard, choosing "Code First From Database" won't include stored procedures, for whatever reason.  For me, the correct option was "EF Designer from Database".  Not only did I get the new tables AND stored procedures, but it also generated the edmx file that the first option wouldn't create.

Comment: Except Visual Studio won't let me change the data connection for some reason, it is skipping past Choose your data connection and disabling the Previous button. Argh!

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar problem with Code First. I followed all the steps mentioned on the question, but the model for the table was not being generated.

- Build, Clean Solution
- Delete conn strings from  in web.config
- Delete all files in Models folder
- Right click on Models folder, Add, New Item
- Select ADO.NET Entity Data Model
- Add name to Model
- Select Code First from database
- Select New Connection
- Save Connection Settings in web.config - Checked

I found out it was because the table did not have a primary key. 
So I altered the table

```
[OrderId] [int] not null identity(1,1) primary key,
```

and it worked.

In case anyone runs into this, I hope it helps.

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem and it turned out to be the SQL user being used did not have select access to the newly created tables.

I ran GRANT SELECT ON [*tablename*] to [*sqluser*] on the database for all the new tables. You could also just add the sql user to a server role like sysadmin.

Running Update Model from Database then showed the new tables.

Answer (score 1):

I removed a table and did not see it to re-add it. I had incosistent EDMX file. I had to remove all references to that table from Model Browser window when editting EDMX file, than the table reappeared in EDMX editor and I was able to re-add it.

As proposed bellow by Mukesh Kumar (thanks), you can do it in text editor (but you have to know what you are doing), but I would go for this solution as the last possibility not to create some more inconsistencies in EDMX file.

Comment: I opened the EDMX file in a text editor and looked for the object name's occurrence in it. Then, I found one occurrence and deleted that XML line from the file and saved it. After deleting it, the ADD wizard started showing the object. Thanks, Honza.